# How to remove text and symbols middle to the end of a text string in r?

Tags: r, string

I have several strings of text where at the end of the country name is [4] or [8] or [3] I.E. digits 1-20

ex1: Bulgaria[6]

how do I remove the [6] and just have Bulgaria?

ex2: 100 Haddon Ave, Westmont, NJ

how to remove all the info after the commas to just get 100 Haddon Ave ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are regular expressions, implemented in R with functions like `gsub` or my preferred `stringr` package. You provide a pattern that matches the text you want to keep, at least with `str_extract`. Here, the first pattern is `".*(?=\\[\\d\\])"`, which means take any characters (`.*`) that precede `[`, a digit, and `]` (`?=\\[\\d\\])`). You need to use `\` to escape certain special characters. The second is similar, saying take characters that precede `,`. There's an extra `?` after the `.*` because this finds the shortest match possible, else you would get `100 Haddon Ave, Westmont` instead of just `100 Haddon Ave`. You can alternatively match for the thing you *don't* want to keep, and use `str_replace` to replace it with nothing `""`. This lets you avoid using lookarounds (the `(?=)` part) which can sometimes be fiddly.

I recommend looking more deeply into regular expressions, including lookarounds. Try the [strings chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html) of R for Data Science or the RStudio strings [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf).

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract("Bulgaria[6]", ".*(?=\\[\\d\\])")
#> [1] "Bulgaria"
str_extract("100 Haddon Ave, Westmont, NJ", ".*?(?=,)")
#> [1] "100 Haddon Ave"
# Alternatively, avoid having to use lookarounds:
str_replace("Bulgaria[6]", "\\[\\d\\]", "")
#> [1] "Bulgaria"
str_replace("100 Haddon Ave, Westmont, NJ", ",.*$", "")
#> [1] "100 Haddon Ave"
```

Created on 2018-03-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
sub("\\[\\d+\\]$", "", 'some words[6]')
#[1] "some words"

sub(",.*", "", "100 Haddon Ave, Westmont, NJ")
#[1] "100 Haddon Ave"
```